# Let's make the "Badges" title in the profile a link!

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, profile-page

In the profile section of a user, when we scroll down to the badges section, I see the Badges title is not a link to the badges section in the **Activity** tab:

[image: Badges section on the profile of a user on SO]

My feature request is to also make the **Badges** title also link to the [user's badges tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=badges)

Comment: It not being a link is consistent with the other headers on that page...

Comment: Related: [Make titles clickable for reputation/badges blocks in profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325574/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for the link. I was not knowing that we are supposed to look for feature requests on MSE also

Comment: This is something that we will consider. I added the `status-review` to [the question linked on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325574/51), as that also includes what you are requesting here.